# Applying different fills simultaneously in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, fill

I have multiple elements with  different stroke colours. I would like to fill all the elements with  their individual outer stroke colours. Is there a way to do this without having to apply outer stroke colour to the fill individually for  each element?

Comment: Well you can write a sript for it. But why would you end up here?

Comment: `Shift+X` makes fill and stroke switch places in the selected object(s). But this would only be helpful in your case if we are talking about like line icons, that don't have a fill at all and you don't mind losing the stroke... and it might be an issue if some the objects have fills and strokes.

Comment: @Joonas it doe not work if you have more than one color in the seletion though

Answer (score 1):

I can think of something to do it faster but still individually :
Shift+clic with the Eyedropper will apply the color you click, to what is selected in the tool panel (stroke or fill).

That way you can just select the fill in the tool panel, and shift/click on your stroke with the Eyedropper to change the fill of your selected element.